# Starting with Ruby 1.9.x, Rails 3, and/or Merb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, merb

I need to spend some serious time reading about changes in Ruby 1.9.1 and upcoming Rails 3/Merb. Can people suggest any articles to read?

Not really looking for one answer, just kinda looking for a compilation of resources people are using to keep up with what's coming and what currently exists, so if you stop by, let me know what you're looking at. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails3 is moving really fast. Updates from books or blog entry is not sufficient enough to keep up with the changes that is happening in Rails3. So I would suggest follow Rails in Github instead, although it might seem scary but I found it much more effective.

Comment: Why is it sad that it's moving fast? We want it finished and released, right?

Comment: It is sad if you only look at the updates for Rails3 only from blog or books. That's why I said it is better to look at the feeds updates from github instead.

Answer (score 2):

articles about Rails 3 - [Yehuda Katz's blog](http://yehudakatz.com/tags/rails-3/)

Answer (score 1):

[Rails 3 in Action](http://www.manning.com/katz/) looks like a good place to start.  There is an early access edition available.

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful for 1.9
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEkJvvGEtB4

Answer (score 0):

The changelogs for the respective facets of Rails is where I get my information from.